# How do I "return index(request)" on successful form submit in Django 1.11

Tags: django, forms, toastr

I am trying to use Toastr to pass status messages upon completion of a form.  If the form is valid it returns you to the index using "return index(request)"  I want to pass context through this.

I am running Python 3.6 and Django 1.11, using Modelforms.  I have tried passing context=var_list as well as passing the variables individually.

Line 15-34 of my views.py

```
def add(request):
    form = CustomerForm()

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CustomerForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            notification_vars = {"toastr_title": "SUCCESS!", 
                                 "toastr_message": "The Customer has been added to the database", 
                                 "toastr_type": "success",}
            return index(request, context=notification_vars) // THIS IS WHAT I NEED TO WORK

    page_vars = { "page_title": "Add Customer", 
                  "page_icon": "fa-address-book",
                  "toastr_title": "", 
                  "toastr_message": "", 
                  "toastr_type": "",
                  "form": form}
return render(request, 'customers/add.html', context=page_vars)
```

This is the toaster code in my footer, and why I always have to pass the variables as blank unless I want to pass a message

```
{% if toastr_message %}
    <script>
        var title   = '{{ toastr_title }}',
            message = '{{ toastr_message }}',
            type    = '{{ toastr_type }}',
            options = {};

        toastr[type](message, title, options);
    </script>
{% endif %}
```

What I want to do is on successful form submission, it passes the context back tot he index page and fills the script in the footer so the success message pops up.

Currently, it comes back telling me I have an unexpected variable Context, or if I pass the variables directly, it tells me there is a syntax issue

Comment: consider using django messages https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/messages/

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out.  I needed to make sure my Index could take context, but also make it so that if no context is passed it still works.

```
def index(request,context={"toastr_title":"","toastr_message":"", "toastr_type":"" }):
    customer_list = Customers.objects.order_by('Name')
    page_vars = { "page_title": "Customers", 
                  "page_icon": "fa-address-book",
                  "toastr_title": context['toastr_title'], 
                  "toastr_message": context['toastr_message'], 
                  "toastr_type": context['toastr_type'],
                  "customer_records": customer_list}
    return render(request, 'customers/index.html', context=page_vars)
```

Comment: No, this is not the right thing to do. You always need to redirect after a successful submission.